# Logarithmic or square root transformation for econometric modeling

Tags: r, data-transformation, econometrics, linear-model, panel-data

I am doing econometric research on firm financial ratios. Using linear panel data modeling, I am going to transform some predictors in order to reduce variance. At this regard, I am uncertain about using the logarithmic or square root transformation. Is there a general guidance? I would like to use the square root one to allow for natural zero values, but I see that many papers prefer logarithmic transform. So, my questions are:

1. Is there a rational approach to choose independent variables transformations?
2. Is there a tool ( maybe a R package) that helps in identifying the optimal transformation for independent variables within the ( panel) linear regression framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should choose transformations of independent variables based on domain-specific knowledge regarding the process that creates the relationship. If you don't have such knowledge and want to use a purely data-driven approach I would recommend using a non-parametric approach such as smoothers/generalized additive models instead.

Comment: The biggest deal with predictors is whatever brings the relationship closer to additive and linear.

Answer (score 1):

BoxCox can be used for this purpose (`car` package), also the square root is usually preferred when you have Poisson data, that is variance increases with mean, while logarithmic is preferred when your data is exponential in nature.

Although this may be domain specific, maybe people prefer the logarithmic transformation in econometric modeling for some unknown (to me) reason. You should check some sources, if you can find some reasoning behind it.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that OP wants to transform the DV but they say they want to transform predictors.

Comment: Not necessarily, the same procedure can be applied to the IV's.

Comment: "the square root is usually preferred when you have Poisson data" does only make sense if you talk about a transformation of the DV.